# VueJS: como passar dados de um array para outro array?

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

Eu tenho o seguinte problema: tenho duas listas separadas e preciso passar os dados selecionados (checkbox) para a outra lista, removendo o item selecionado e o colocando na outra lista (juntamente com o seu cabeçalho).

Tentei fazer um push porém não consigo copiar a estrutura da primeira lista, para a segunda.

Segue um exemplo montado para ilustrar melhor a pergunta:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    cuitsCuota: [{}],
    cuitsEmisora: [
      {
        nombre: "12 21365896 7 | Mercerias Gutierrez",
        id: 0,
        comercios: [
          {
            nombre: "1254789 | Hilos de Oro | Villa Urquiza",
            id: 0
          },
          {
            nombre: "1265897 | Mis Botones | Villa Urquiza",
            id: 1
          },
          {
            nombre: "1211897 | Mis Botones | Villa Urquiza",
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        nombre: "30 25665877 1 | Mercerias Rodriguez",
        id: 1,
        comercios: [
          {
            nombre: "11 21365811 1 | Mercerias Rodriguez",
            id: 0
          },
          {
            nombre: "99 21365811 1 | Mercerias Rodriguez",
            id: 1
          },
          {
            nombre: "77 21365811 1 | Mercerias Rodriguez",
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    testando: function() {
      var self = this;
      var values = [];

      console.log(this.cuitsEmisora);
      this.cuitsEmisora.forEach(function(i, el) {
        console.log(values);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.c-box-cfc-comercios__emisora{
  background:#ccc;
  float:left;
  margin-right:15px;
}
.option-chk-lbl{
  color:blue;
}
.c-box-cfc-comercios__cuotacuota{
  background:red;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="c-box-cfc-comercios c-box-cfc-comercios__emisora">
    <div class="c-lista-box">
      <div class="option-wrapper" v-for="cuit in cuitsEmisora">
        <div class="option-chk-lbl">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkLabel" :id="'cuit'+cuit.id">
          <label :for="'cuit'+cuit.id">
                            {{cuit.nombre}}
                        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option-chk" v-for="comercio in cuit.comercios">
          <input type="checkbox" :id="'comercio'+cuit.id+comercio.id" :value="'comercio'+cuit.id+comercio.id">
          <label :for="'comercio'+cuit.id+comercio.id">
                            <span class="box"></span>
                            <span class="check-text">{{comercio.nombre}}</span>
                        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button v-on:click="testando()">
                TO RIGHT
            </button>


  <div class="c-box-cfc-comercios c-box-cfc-comercios__cuotacuota">
    <div class="c-lista-box">
      <div class="option-wrapper" v-for="cuit in cuitsCuota">
        <div class="option-chk-lbl">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkLabel" :id="'cuit'+cuit.id">
          <label :for="'cuit'+cuit.id">
                            {{cuit.nombre}}
                        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option-chk" v-for="comercio in cuitsCuota.comercios">
          <input type="checkbox" :id="'comercio'+cuit.id+comercio.id">
          <label :for="'comercio'+cuit.id+comercio.id">
                            <span class="box"></span>
                            <span class="check-text">{{comercio.nombre}}</span>
                        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No caso eu preciso passar o comercio selecionado da 'cuitsEmisora' para o 'cuitsCuota' porém, sendo montada a mesma estrutura.